# MYSQL Error 1406 "Data to long" in blob field

Tags: mysql, blob

I obtain this error when I try to insert a text that is approx. 85K long in a blob field.

I tried also to change the field to longblob ant to turn off strict mode, but with no result.

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

try change the column type to text in de BBDD

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the data type into **LONGTEXT** and then try again

Comment: Done with no positive result.
The strange thing is that, if I cut & paste the text directly in the field, I have no problem. 
I fill the table with a  PHP routine and a mysql_real_escape_string() command

Comment: Are you pasting directly in the database?

Comment: Yes, I paste it directly into the field using MySQLYog that is a Win MySQL administration tool.